# Are questions on specific DAPPs on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Sooner or later people will ask questions on specific DAPPs. I guess we need to make a decisions whether or not this os on or off topic.

We also might come to a middle ground where some canonical DAPPs like a wallet, name register, ... are on topic but a random gambling DAPP is not.

Answer (score 10):

My vote is that they are on-topic, as long as the question still relates to the platform in some way (i.e. not if it is user support for passing a level in a game that just so happens to use ethereum-based tokens or something way off track like that).

Answer (score 9):

So far so good.

So, it shouldn't be an issue till now. As this is still in the infant stage, having a very open policy is very important.

Let's gradually narrow the scope down on specific questions and topics once the conflicts(or conflicting posts/questions) start popping up on the site!

**So, let's be open to all the questions about DPP's now.**  It's very early to judge with a very limited set of questions!

Answer (score 7):

I believe questions about DAPPs should be on topic always, unless there is another stackexchange site about it in the same way Ethereum talk is allowed in Bitcoin's stackexchange site but when this site goes live I suppose all Ethereum related questions will be migrated here.

My reasoning for it is that talking about DAPPs here will increase this site's popularity. Form another perspective you can see allowing DAPPs indefinitely here is better because there is no other place in stackexchange where you can talk about DAPPs specifically. However, I do believe that talking about specifics things happening in DAPPs should be discouraged. For example: Augur doesn't have their own stackexchange so questions and answers about Augur are welcome here, such as:

- "How do I get reputation in Augur"
- "How does reputation in Augur work"
- "How does Augur relate to Ethereum".
- "Tutorials about prediction in Augur"

But questions like:

- "Who is going to win the 2016 presidential race, help me decide" shouldn't be allowed, plus I suppose Augur will have forums where users can talk about this kind of questions (specially the ones regarding their own predictions which by the way in most cases are opinion based questions too).

Answer (score 4):

I feel that this SE should be about the entire ecosystem, the platform and the community. That certainly includes topics on code, (behavioral) economics, governance (not necessarily politics), mathematics, cryptography, and definately dApps!