# Do we allow a dApp name to be a tag?

Tags: discussion

I don't think we should.
Example: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metamask

Comment: Is it possible we merge this question with [this](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/220/87)? My answer over there is valid for both threads.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @mids "generally speaking; if we allow questions about specific dapps, it makes sense to me that we also allow them to be tagged as such."

So we can make this be dependent on
[Are questions on specific DAPPs on or off topic?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/are-questions-on-specific-dapps-on-or-off-topic) ?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case I would reason that `metamask` is more than a "regular" dApp, it is "mist for your webbrowser". If we allow `mist` as tag (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mist), I would also allow other wallet/browsers.

More generally speaking; if we allow questions about specific dapps, it makes sense to me that we also allow them to be tagged as such.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you. In general, a tag that only applies to one question shouldn't be a tag. This would apply to questions about a specific, relatively unknown Dapp. It doesn't make sense to make a tag for every single one, but it might make sense to make one for common/popular Dapps, especially ones that effectively act as libraries.

Comment: How do you know it will only apply to one question in the future?