# Do we want to tag products and services according to their classification?

Tags: discussion

Do we want to tag products and services according to their classification?
Or do we "prepare" for the future by having specific tags?

I think we have mainly been doing the former.  The latter could lead to clutter or more "commercial" stuff in these early days, but specific tags may be needed or better in the long run?

Example of former:
using [explorers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explorers) instead of specific tags like etherscan, ethercamp, etc

Do we want to continue using [exchanges](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchanges) or start having tags for the different exchanges? Example: [How does EtherScan know I am sending to a Shapeshift/Poloniex wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2798/42)

---

Related is [Do we allow a dApp name to be a tag?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/do-we-allow-a-dapp-name-to-be-a-tag)

But there's going to be many more DApps (than exchanges or explorers) so I think we are treating DApps on a more case-by-case basis...?

Answer (score 1):

*Below is my personal opinion and I would like to stand corrected if there is any other practice more common on Stack Exchange sites.*

---

**Yes**, we want to have most specific tags. It's always good to have rather [etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etherscan) than [explorers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/explorers). Or rather [shapeshift](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshift) than [exchanges](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exchanges).

- [etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etherscan) covers all questions related to the blockchain explorer named *EtherScan*. I see there is a valid application as there can be alot of questions be raised, like wrong balances, misleading transaction displays or general questions about API usage.
- [shapeshift](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshift) is very valid as ShapeShift is fully integrated in the Ethereum Wallet. A lot of questions already popped up related to this one, the only downside is, often people don't know they are dealing with ShapeShift at all.

From the [help center](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

This also applies in my eyes to products and applications ([including DApps](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/87)). If users or developers of a certain app or product -- [related to our site topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tour) -- have any questions regarding this, it's always good to tag them with that specific tags. This also allows maintainers of Shapeshift or EtherScan in this example to subscribe to tags and quickly react to issues on Stack Exchange.

As a popular example, I would like to link the [[iphone]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) tag on Stack Overflow. It's clearly a product, but often more specific than [[ios]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) or [[objective-c]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

---

And while we are at it, we should also discuss the other direction: meta-tags like [introducing-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/introducing-ethereum), and so on. See [this beautiful blog post by Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 5chdn (but I talked too much for a comment).

Having the most specific tags for things is always good - especially if there is content to fill them.

Examples:

- [shapeshift](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shapeshift) is a good tag as there are quite a few questions that are specifically about Shapeshift and not much else.
- A question should not be tagged Shapeshift if it merely mentions that service but the question really has to do with, say, confirmations.
- When creating a new tag, the community member should do their best to retroactively tag related posts as well. IMO, no tag should have less than ~5 questions. This helps with discovery (more on that later).
- [In this discussion](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/do-we-allow-a-dapp-name-to-be-a-tag), [metamask](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metamask) comes up as an example. At this point, I don't know if there is enough content for metamask to be a worthwhile tag. However, in 6 months there absolutely may be.

The key here is that the question is a question where the main issues / question / content pertains specifically to that product or service.

- Yes: "How does etherscan put names on addresses?" is a question specifically about [etherscan](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etherscan). Having an etherscan tag would be worthwhile here.
- Maybe: "How do I view my account balance using etherscan?" is not as deserving as it really pertains to any blockchain explorer, not just etherscan. It could be tagged etherscan and explorer or just explorers. (IMO, it doesn't really hurt to have more tags as long as they aren't off-topic). The question would also be helped by being edited to refer to all blockchain explorers.
- No: "Why did my transaction fail? ... I looked on etherscan and it says Out of Gas..." is *really* not deserving of the etherscan tag as etherscan is simply mentioned while the issue has to do with transactions, not the blockchain explorer.

> "A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."

First, developers of many of the products and services are active on StackExchange, so having a tag that they can specifically go to to answer questions could be super helpful in that sense.

Secondly, I don't think that description covers the full use case of tags in Ethereum StackExchange's case. While this is absolutely true for larger communities (ie: StackOverflow), at this point tags also help immensely with discovery and learning. Maybe I'm the only one that ever views related questions in a tag, but I learn heaps by reading and examining discussions on threads - even threads I have no intention of being able to answer.

With such a new technology, there aren't a ton of blogs or discussions online about a lot of the things that are happening right now. If I want to learn about CSS, I have tutorials, blogs, books, lynda.com, and so much more. If I want to learn more about Solidity, I have (1) the github repo / readme (1b) MAYBE one Ethereum blog post (2) a couple reddit threads and (3) StackExchange. The Etheruem StackExchange is especially helpful in learning how the specifics of a technology and how real people are using it.

Comment: I think you run one of these services? ;)

Comment: You are correct. I think if MyEtherWallet had a tag, I would probably obsessively check it. Most people reach out to us via email or reddit message to get support and questions answered though. At times, those support questions aren't even about MyEtherWallet at all, and I point them to StackExchange. :P