# Are questions about other blockchains on-topic?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, topic

Considering we are funding a DogeRelay Bounty, I suspect we may have questions about it, which I'd say is perfectly on-topic... but, I suspect we may also have errant questions about the Doge chain itself.

My preference is to be inclusive to bring in the widest community possible (essentially all cryptos and just tag with dogecoin, dash, etc.), but I can understand arguments against it to maintain focus on the Ethereum ecosystem alone.

How do others feel we should balance these community Vs focus type goals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that we should allow other cryptocurrencies to be discussed as long as they are in reference to or compared to Ethereum. Posts that are overly negative or positive of either Ethereum or any other cryptocurrency platforms in the post should be deleted or the user warned.

Once the Dogethereum relay is running there are going to be a lot of questions about it, so we need to make sure that we have rules set up to allow the spirit of innovations and cross-currency features that Ethereum offers to be allowed.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Q and A site, and the topic is Ethereum.

I would say that questions that passively involve other blockchains are fine so long as the main subject matter is Ethereum.

That is to say I think:

"How do i integrate Dogecoin with the Ethereum blockchain" is OK (albeit vague)

**BUT**

"How do I do x, y, and z with Blockstream" is not.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also in favor of including technical questions about Dogethereum and other blockchains built upon Ethereum. The reason is that Dogethereum users & developers (and other blockchains users & developers) don't have their own SE where they can make questions. So rather than having them ask questions on Bitcoin's SE, Ethereum SE should be the to-go place to ask their questions. In that way Ethereum's SE will increase in size and in diversity which is always desirable in a site like this. This is a [similar argument to one I made regarding Dapps](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/36/116). So in my opinion, unless these other blockchains have their own SE site and these sidechains are related to Ethereum in some way I believe Ethereum.stackexchange should welcome all questions as far as they and follow the guidelines of this SE site.

I know when this Ethereum's SE was proposed in area51 there was no intention of widening to other blockchains, however this meta is useful to discuss changes regarding the initial approach to Ethereum SE.

Answer (score 3):

When this site was first proposed on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) was an argument for everyone interested getting involved on [bitcoin.stackexchange.com](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) under an [ethereum] tag. Seeing as we decided not to do that but just focus on Ethereum I would have thought there is no argument for widening this site to include other cryptos. Those who are interested can either get involved on bitcoin.se or start a new cryptocurrency proposal on area51.